# Flexible storage and retrieval of motion capture data

Tags: c, database, machine-learning

I want to flexibly access motion capture data from C/C++ code.  We currently have a bunch of separate files (.c3d format).  We can expect the full set of data to be several hours long and tracking about 50 markers (4 floats each) per frame, sampled at 60 hz.  So we're probably looking at a couple of gigabytes of data.

I'd like to have a database that can hold the data, allowing it to be relatively rapidly retrieved, augmented, and modified.  I like to be able to apply labels to the data and retrieve sequences of frames by label, time indices (e.g., frame 400-2000, or every 30th frame) or other potential criteria.

Does such a thing already exist?  Could I do it with SQLite for example?  Does anyone have an intuition for what kind of performance I might get?

Currently, I'm just loading one .c3d file at a time and processing it.  I haven't yet begun to apply meta-data/labels to sequences.  I'll be accessing the sequences for visualization, statistical analysis, and training for machine-learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store multi-gigabytes of data with a known schema you might want to look into a binary flat file database. Of those available, I would recommend [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/). It is not a relational database like SQLite, but provides rich support for array and matrix data with excellent performance. It also includes MPI support, if you ever expand your machine-learning onto a cluster.

Comment: Definitely comes with 'some assembly required'.  I'm trying to make some quick tests for comparison.

Comment: They have a number of visualization tools available which is also helpful.